# Type mis match error in javascript while calling C# COM component

Tags: c#, javascript, html, c#-4.0, com

I Created an Com Component in C# and try to access in Javascript.

My C# Method is

```
Class myComComponent
{
    private int[] nAllData;    
    public int[] GetArray(int index)
            {
              //Some Logic here that will return integer type of array{1,12,15,48,1452,45}
                return nAllData;
            }
}
```

call it from javascript but it gives me an type mismatch error.

Javascript Code

```
 function MyComComponent_onload() {
           try {
               var nAllData = new Array();
               for (var i = 0; i<= 5; i++)
                   {
                        nAllData.push(myComComponent.GetArray(i));
                     }
                }
                catch (err) 
                {
                    alert(err.message);
                }
            }
    <html>
    <head>
 <object id="myComComponent" name="myComComponent" classid="clsid:4794D615-BE51-4A1E-B1BA-453F6E9337C4">
    </head>
    <body onload="MyComComponent_onload();">
    //// Html Code goes here
    </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: You c# function returns an array of integers, so you need a 2D array in your javascript to store these arrays... I'm I right?

Comment: @Giwrgos Tsopanoglou How I can do this. I dont know how to convert it. can u please tell me in brief

Comment: I haven't ever combined c# and javascript and I'm not an expert. Maybe you could try adding "nAllData[i] = new Array()" in your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript can only use the Automation-compatible subset of COM. Arrays of integers are not part of that subset.

You need to return a SAFEARRAY of VARIANT to be compatible with JavaScript, or alternatively return an object with the IEnumVariant interface (so foreach works), and IDispatch with an indexed default property (so indexing with square brackets works).

Comment: I think your methedology is correct can you give me an example for better understanding